# How to modify the "Filtrar: " Label that can be seen in datatables list?

Tags: gvnix

How to modify the "Filtrar: " Label that can be seen in datatables list.
It seems that there are no label properties for this. I try to look in application.properties and messages.properties but is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatables configuration and i18n strings are located into `src/main/resources/datatables*.properties` files.

Good luck!. Chema.